# Add attribute link in admin panel is showing as page isnt working!

Tags: magento2, database, product-attribute, custom-attributes, additional-information

When we try to create an additional attribute from the admin panel,it shows the following error:
This page isn’t working
restaurantware.local is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Please see log in var/log/system.log

Comment: [Tue Sep 25 12:04:14.734632 2018] [php7:notice] [pid 4216] [client 127.0.0.1:60534] PHP Error:  Call to a member function getDisplayOption() on boolean in /var/www/html/staging/restaurantwarecom/app/code/WeltPixel/LayeredNavigation/Observer/Edit/Tab/Front/WpProductAttributeFormBuildFrontTabObserver.php on line 412
[Tue Sep 25 12:04:14.734692 2018] [php7:notice] [pid 4216] [client 127.0.0.1:60534] PHP Stack trace:

Comment: You have error in your custom module  WeltPixel/LayeredNavigation Please disable it and then check